# Trying to get index from a $_SESSION foreach loop PHP

Tags: php

I am making a shopping cart and I am at the end of the payment process.The problem I have is trying to get the names in the shopping cart into my database. Every time I do it only the last item gets entered in instead of the whole thing if there is more then 1.Also wondered if there is a way to enter into the SQL row based on the number of the item.Ex of what i am trying to achive. In the cart there is apple,orange,banana

apple ->order1

orange->order2

banana->order3

**What I get**

apple->doesn't go in

orange->doesn't go in

banana->order1

**PHP**

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){

    //keep track of how mnay products are in the shopping cart
    $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

    //create sequantial array for matching array keys to products id's
    $row_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'id');

    if (!in_array(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'), $row_ids)){
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count] = array
        (
            'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'),
            'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
            'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
            'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
        );   
    }
    else {echo="do nothing";}
        }
    }

}

if (isset($_POST['payment_process'])) {

foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product) {
        echo  "<div>".$product['name']."</div>";
    }

}
$payment = "INSERT INTO `payment_info`
    (order1,order2,order3)
    VALUES
    ('".$product['name']."','".$product['name']."','".$product['name']."');";
    mysqli_query($db,$payment);
```

Comment: Put that query in `foreach` loop and it will work as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is complicated for nothing and the way your database is structured, you're limited to 3 items per order and/or payment.

You should have a structure of invoice -> invoice_lines:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && isset($_POST['payment_process'])){

  //keep track of how many products are in the shopping cart if you need
  $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

  $invoice = "INSERT INTO `invoices`
    (date, customer)
    VALUES
    (time(), $_SESSION['customer']);";
  mysqli_query($db,$invoice);
  $new_invoice = mysqli_insert_id($db);

  foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product) {
    $invoice_line = "INSERT INTO `invoice_lines`
      (invoice, id, quantity, price)
      VALUES
      ($new_invoice, $product['id'], $product['quantity'], $product['price']);";
    mysqli_query($db,$invoice_line);
  }
}
else {
  echo="do nothing";
}
```

Obviously, you will need to reshape your database structure accordingly and add required code to calculate invoice's total.

Comment: thanks alot for helping me you saved me so many hrs really appreciate it ^_^